# Run an application on start up as administrator in windows xp

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-administration

We want to start one application (exe file) on start up running as administrator so that users cannot kill it. Is this possible in windows xp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Start the application as a service. On Win-Xp the Services can show at least TrayIcons, I'm not sure about windows/forms.

To easily turn any application into a service, you can use [srvany](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) from the [Windows 2003 Server Ressource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657).

b) The Windows Task Sheduler is capable of running applications as different users incl. admins (using this method, no windows will be shown).

c) You can run `at hh:mm /INTERACTIVE cmd` to start a process as `SYSTEM-User` which can interact with the users desktop.

Comment: We tried to do this from Resource kit but for some reason that service is not starting